# Android device cant access a website

Tags: wifi, android

The company i work for is having a weird problem.

They have a website.  You can access their website from any device, anywhere, easily.  But when we are in the office, android device that are on their wifi cannot connect to the website.  Computer can, iphones can, just android.  And just on their specific wifi.  And if you have Opera on your android, you'll be able to access their website from their wifi.  But if you are using an other browser on an android device on their wifi, it will time out.  I can access other website, just not theirs.

Any clue why?

Comment: the tech guys mess with user agent filtering on wifi ?

Comment: I'd start by tracking it through logging backwards.  Does the webserver see a request from the android device?  If not, does the firewall/switches/wifi controller/ap/etc. working your way back from the webserver see any requests?  If not, then I'd mess with getting an app that allows for web logging or network logging.  Most though require root access.

Comment: Small update : if i type de ip address on my phone while being on their wifi it works. Im really lost on what can cause those troubles.  I check their router, nothing special there either to explain.  i used a packet tracer to try and see whats going on, but so far what i can tell is that theres no answer from the web server.  I can ping both the ip adress and the web adress from the phone as well

Answer (score 0):

If I may share my experience and how I resolved this issue, old as the post is. I had a very similar situation, I host my own website on one PC and mailserver on another PC and I simply could not get my Android 11 phone to connect to either the website or the mailserver using the hostnames ([www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and mail.mydomain.com respectively) when connected to Wi-Fi. I had my D-Link DIR-825 router set up with virtual servers pointing to the correct internal IP addresses for the relevant services. Turns out, though, I had to enable NAT loopback on the virtual servers and as soon as I did that, hostnames resolved perfectly for both website and mailserver. I hope this helps someone.